# How to get Azure Role Instance using Windows Azure Powershell commands

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to get Azure Instances for a deployed service and then to check if all the instance statuses are "Running".  How can I accomplish this with the Windows Azure Powershell cmdlets?

Comment: I have tried Get-AzureRole but it returns only RoleNames and InstanceCounts but not status for each instance

Answer (score 10):

Here is the command you are looking for:

```
$NonReadyInstances = (Get-AzureDeployment mikewoazuredemo -Slot Production).RoleInstanceList | Where-Object { $_.InstanceStatus -ne "ReadyRole" } | ft -Property RoleName, InstanceName, InstanceStatus    

$NonReadyInstances
```

This will get you list of any Instance in any role that isn't in the ready status.  If you want the ones that are ready change the -ne to -e in the Where-Object.  The statuses for instances can be found in the REST API Documentation for the [Get Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460804.aspx) operation which this cmdlet calls under the hood.